# Wordpress: How to include JavaScript as block element

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

What is the correct way to add JavaScript in a block to WordPress?

I have the following JavaScript, which I want to add into a specific position of a WordPress page:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><br>
<script id="widget_id_2082" type="text/javascript" src="https://11076.wundercoach.net/api/v1/jsonp/full_filterable_list/b93c78f1-77b9-4096-ba1a-adb1d7fdbb2e.js?locale=de/b93c78f1-77b9-4096-ba1a-adb1d7fdbb2e.js" async="true"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I can't add it to the theme or the page in general, because the code is from a third party provider and will render a widget at the position where it is added.

If I add a normal paragraph and put the code into it with the code editor:

```html
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>
<!-- [The code from above] -->
</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Then this is correctly displayed on the real page. But on the administration page I get wired empty tags marked in yellow:

[image]

Why is that? Is there a block element in which I can add javascript (and css tags), which is displayed as something like "JavaScript block" or even some text in the admin panel that I could edit?

I don't want my customer to see this wired tags and maybe delete them by chance. So I want a user editing the page, understand that code lives in this element.

Also I don't want to add any of the above JavaScript into elements of a plugin or the theme, since the JavaScript needs to be able to be updated by my customer, which doesn not have access to the WordPress sources.

Is that possible?

Comment: WordPress already loads jQuery (3.7.0) so you may have problems if you load it again. The best way to do this is with a plugin that implements a shortcode. Is that technique available to you (do you have the time and capability to do that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Custom HTML" block types to add that code.

Although you are adding scripts, they are just HTML tags, so this block will do what you need.

[image: Add block -> Custom HTML]

Comment: That works as I imagined. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. Script and Link tags are stripped off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple tool(**WPCode**), which comes in the form of a WordPress plugin. It will help you add many codes in many languages within WordPress.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).